# Cannot delete or rename files as administrator from GUI in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, privileges

I want to be able to right click a file as superuser and delete it, select 'move to' or rename it.   Basically, any of the things that I can do from the command line as a superuser.

I'm logged into my administrator account and can do any of these things from the command line using `sudo`, but I don't have the privelages in the GUI.

If I right click on a given file as administrator I cannot cut, rename, move to, or move it to the trash.  What gives?

Comment: Are these files you're supposed to have ownership of? There is no root account in Ubuntu and even an admin account may not have sufficient permissions to delete certain files.

Comment: this is a file that I created from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a file manager with administrative privileges by typing:

```
gksudo nautilus &
```

It will prompt you for the password. With the window that opens, you will be able to rename, move, or delete files that need superuser privileges.

Be careful though.